# non negative super martingale

Tags: probability-theory, proof-verification, martingales

Let $(X_n)_{n\geq0}$ be a non-negative supermatingale and $T = \inf\{n \geq 0 : X_n = 0\}$. Show that on the event
$\{T < \infty\}$,
$X_{T+n} = 0$ for all $n \geq 0$ a.s.

My approach: $0 \leq E[X_{T+n}|\mathcal{F}_{T+n-1}] \leq X_{T+n-1} \leq \cdots \leq X_T = 0$. So, $X_{T+n} = 0$ for all $n$. Is this correct?

Comment: Or, simply (by Optional Sampling), $0\le E[X_{T+n}\,|\,\mathcal F_T]\le X_T=0$ on $\{T<\infty\}$.

Answer (score 1):

$X_n$ is uniformly bounded from below, so it converges a.s. to an integrable random variable for Doob's Supermartingale Convergence Theorem.

This fact together with the event $\{T < \infty\}$ allows us to use the Optional Stopping Theorem, so

$\mathsf{E}[X_{T+n}|\mathscr{F}_{T}]\le X_{T}=0$.

But since $X$ is also bounded below, and is non negative, we have $\forall n\ge 1$

$0 \le \mathsf{E}[X_{T+n}|\mathscr{F}_{T}]\le X_{T}=0$.

Comment: @Parsiv: Why do we need Supermartingale Convergence theorem here?

Comment: To justify that the hypotheses for the application of the optional sampling theorem are satisfied, i.e. the fact that the supermartingale has a last element (check eg Karatzas & Shreve (Brownian Motion & Stochastic Calculus) p19).

Comment: This proves that the $E[X_{T+n} | F_T] = 0$ for every positive n, but how does it follow from this that $X_{T+n}$ is $0$ for every positive n?